# How to implement DRM in React on VPS

Tags: reactjs, vps, drm

I am looking to implement DRM on my learning management system React app to block unauthorized content downloads. Using VPS as web hosting as well as content hosting. The VPS is running on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are talking about video content.

Assuming this is the case you need to either use a video hosting service which has a DRM service included, such as Vimeo, Brightcove etc, or else host and stream the video yourself, perhaps using a streaming solution - see below, and add the DRM when you stream.

For the latter you will need a service from one or all of the main DRM providers deepening on what platforms you want to cover (very high level - Widevine for Google browsers and devices, FairPlay for Apple and PlayReady for Microsoft but some exceptions and caveats) or else with a multiDRM provider who will interface with the DRM provider for you.

If you just want a simple and cheaper protection you may find a combination of authentication, secure URLs and very basic Clear Key encryption may be enough for you, but again the complexity to stream efficiently can be large so it may be worth looking at existing streaming server solutions like Wowza, AWS Media Services, Azure Media Services etc.